# What's the meaning of とこに?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, particles

I pretty much couldn't find this とこに in my dictionary so I was wondering what it means.
Here's the context:

> あんなとこにタオル落ちてる

Also, is あんな a slang for あのな?

*Edit.* I forgot, my translation would be:

> "The towel has fallen"

But yeah, I don't get the meaning of anna tokoni.

Answer (score 2):

「とこ」[is essentially](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/158493/m0u/) an abbreviated way to say「ところ」.

「あんな」is actually part of the 「こんな」、「そんな」、「あんな」list of words... and it typically refers to *"that kind of thing"* (or in this case, *"that type of place"* or *"there"*.)

As far as the translation goes, thanks for adding that to your question!  Perhaps this phrase could also be translated as:

> There's a towel on the ground *over there*.

Comment: thank you very much summea c: I didn't get that とこ was a verb I thought it was an adverb together with に. Everything is clear now thanks (:

Comment: @Dai とこ is never a verb.  In this case, it's a noun.

Comment: @snailboat right とこ= floor in this case gha I just confused things thanks for telling me^^

Comment: @Dai Although とこ can mean "floor" (in other usages) the actual word here for とこ is just a shortened version of ところ :)

Comment: @summea: I understand your use of italics on "over there" to imply "[you mean that kind of place,] over there [?/!]" but correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Tim Yes, that is why I used the *italics*.  Thank you for noticing ^^;

Comment: Why "essentially"? (What else is it?)